# How can I solve transition problem in onmouseover event?

Tags: javascript, html, css

The picture changes when I hover over the picture, but I can't add a transition effect. Can anyone guide me on how can I achieve that?

```
 <img src="/responsiveweb/2.jpeg" id="image1" alt="" style="width:300px; height:300px; object-fit:contain">



 <script>


        var resim = document.getElementById("image1");

        resim.onmouseover = function() {
            resim.src = "/responsiveweb/3.jpeg";
        }
        resim.onmouseout = function() {
            this.src = "/responsiveweb/2.jpeg";

        }
        resim.style.transition = "all 2s";
    </script>
```

Comment: You can't transition image src files. Transitions require **numbers** to move to/from. You'll need to fade them in/out with opacity or some such.

Comment: I would put both images directly the HTML and use CSS to fade them in/out like @Paulie_D said. I have a pure CSS carousel demo that does this which may be helpful to you https://codepen.io/tedw/pen/bNeqWo